# How to dynamically complement colnames in a list of data.frames by information from a vector

Tags: r, dataframe, functional-programming

I have a `list` of `data.frames` whereas the first column's `colname` in each `data.frame` is supposed to be complemented by dynamic information from a vector.

Example:

```
set.seed(1)
df1 <- data.frame(matrix(sample(32), ncol = 8))
names(df1) <- paste(rep(c("a", "b"), each = 4), 1:4, sep = "")

set.seed(2)
df2 <- data.frame(matrix(sample(32), ncol = 8))
names(df2) <- paste(rep(c("a", "b"), each = 4), 1:4, sep = "")

list_dfs <- list(df1, df2)
add_info <- c("add1", "other")
```

How can I add information from `add_info` to change the `colname` for a1 in df1 to "a1 add1" and a1 in df2 to "a1 add2" in a scalable way within the given `list` structure? The other `colnames` are not supposed to be changed.

I tried several approaches setting `colnames` using `paste0` within `lapply` or a `for` loop and reviewed similar questions on SO but couldn't solve this problem so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
list_dfs <- lapply(1:length(list_dfs), function(i) {
  setNames(list_dfs[[i]],paste(names(list_dfs[[i]]),add_info[[i]]))
})
```

Now the first `dataframe` in the list has its original name concatenated with the first element of `add_info`, the second has its names concatenated with second element of `add_info`. You can easily scale this to longer lists of `data.frame`s and corresponding `add_info`-vectors.

Update:
If you only want to change the first name, do

```
list_dfs <- lapply(1:length(list_dfs), function(i) {
  lastNames <- names(list_dfs[[i]])[2:NCOL(list_dfs[[i]])]
  firstName <- paste(names(list_dfs[[i]])[1],add_info[[i]])
  setNames(list_dfs[[i]],c(firstName,lastNames))
})
```

Comment: Seems like this changes all ```colnames``` but not only the first one in each df.

Comment: Nice, so basically your solution defines the new ```colnames``` via ```setNames``` and information defined in lastNames and firstName. Say I'd like to change the names of the second column instead of the first. Would the solution be ```list_dfs <- lapply(1:length(list_dfs), function(i) {
  lastNames <- names(list_dfs[[i]])[3:NCOL(list_dfs[[i]])]
  secondName <- paste(names(list_dfs[[i]])[2],add_info[[i]])
  firstName <- names(list_dfs[[i]])[1(list_dfs[[i]])]
  setNames(list_dfs[[i]],c(firstName,secondName,lastNames))
})```  ```firstName``` doesn't seem to be correct here.

Comment: Just found the solution for changing only the second column. Pasting the information from the first ```colname``` did the trick ```list_dfs <- lapply(1:length(list_dfs), function(i) {
  lastNames <- names(list_dfs[[i]])[3:NCOL(list_dfs[[i]])]
  secondName <- paste(names(list_dfs[[i]])[2],add_info[[i]])
  firstName <- paste(names(list_dfs[[i]])[1])
  setNames(list_dfs[[i]],c(firstName,secondName,lastNames))
})```. Thanks for your suggestion to tackle the original problem!